# Is it possible to use Auto Layout on some View Controllers and Autoresize on others? (Swift 4)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, autolayout, xcode10, autoresize, ios12

I am trying to use Autoresize on some of my View Controllers Auto Layout on others. Everything looks fine on all device sizes when I use the "View As:" tool in Storyboards. There are no overlaps and everything fits nicely. However, I have Auto Layout Warnings:

[image]

Why am I getting these warnings if nothing is clipping or overlapping? And how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Note the warning is related to **Localization** and it states ***may*** clip, not ***will*** clip. Even though you don't see issues with your current implementation, that doesn't mean you *won't* ever see issues down the road, or if your app is running on a device with a different locale. Either ignore the warnings (at your peril) or add constraints (why don't you want constraints anyway?).

Comment: Autoresize was simply working better with the UIView animation that I am using. Plus, it is much quicker to test and make adjustments using Autoresize. I guess that the answer to my question is NO ... it is NOT possible to use Auto Layout on some View Controllers and Autoresize on others, within the same Storyboard application. A work around this could be to add some of my Views programmatically and then set NSLayout Constraints programmatically for those Views. All while keeping Autoresize settings for the Storyboard Views. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Quick test --- it *is* possible via code to add subviews and set auto-layout constraints to a view when the view controller is in a storyboard with auto-layout turned off. Of course, you can also add a subview and set its `.autoresizingMask` via code to keep things consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not sure what you mean by "quick test", though? Are you suggesting I quickly test your feedback or you already did? Sorry, just not familiar with the term "quick test" in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I could have been more clear. *After my quick test* ... it appears to be no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you don't need to do any special steps, just try adding auto-layout margins using (control + actions told) storyboard and xCode will automatically handles them separately.

Other controllers that you have made ready using Auto-resizing would not be effected by this.

And new controller you made ready with auto-layout would work fine as well.
Hope this would work out for you.

For reference adding 2 screenshots (both are from same xCode project) for you to be clear of that what I am trying to say...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you don't  want to use auto layout just disable it.
select ViewController in storybored,go to file inspecter -> locate the Interface Builder Document section.uncheck use Autolayout.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I gave it a plus one, but unfortunately your answer disables auto layout for all of my View Controllers even if I only have one selected. I was hoping to use Auto Layout on two of my View Controllers and Autoresize on the rest. I will edit my question to clarify this.